# SQLAlchemy showing a UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm getting the following error from Google AppEngine, but I don't have any stacktrace nor more details to find the origin of the issue, I'm hoping someone will know more about the situation to help me out :

> /base/data/home/apps/s~myproject-prod/20170207t172637.399025232647613201/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py:359:
>   UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both
>   arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
>
> return x == y

Here the origin of the code :

```
data = request.get_json()
client_email = clean_str(data.get('email', None))
client = Client.query.filter(Client.email == client_email)
if client is None:
    client = Client(data)
else:
    client.update(data)

client.save()  # ERROR IS THROWN HERE
# I was able to trace it here by logging some text before/after the error.
```

And the model :

```
class Client(db.Model):
    __tablename__  = 'clients'

    id             = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name           = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True, default=None)
    email          = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, index=True)

    details        = db.Column(types.JSON(none_as_null=True), default=None)

    def __init__(self, client_infos):
        self.email = client_infos['email'].lower()
        del(client_infos['email'])
        self.details = json.dumps(client_infos)

    def update(self, data):
        # Some treatment of the data, removing some fields, etc
        self.details = json.dumps(data)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        db.session.add(self)
        if commit:
            db.session.commit()
        return self
```

And the clean_str function :

```
def clean_str(value):
    if not isinstance(value, (str, unicode)):
        return value

    try:
        value = unicode(value, 'utf-8', errors='ignore')
    except:
        pass

    try:
        value = value.encode('utf-8')
    except:
        pass

    return value
```

Does someone know why am I getting that error? Is it because of the `types.JSON`?

Comment: Need a few more details. Is the function _clear_str_ a custom function? What happens if the email is blank? data.get('email', None) returns None, so what is the output of clean_str?

The problem here is probably at Client.query.filter(Client.email=client_email) where the strings being compared are not encoded the same way.

Comment: It should be `Client.email == client_email`.

Comment: @univerio Fixed it, it was a typo on my end, but it's not the issue here. Thanks

Comment: @shish023 I've added the clean_str function, and added a comment on where the issue is raised (on the .save()). I've also added the .save function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this yet but it seems like the problem is that you are trying to compare the *Client.email* which is a string to the user input which you convert to unicode in the *clean_str* function.

One possible solution is to convert the user input to a Python string rather than unicode. But in case you need the input to be unicode for some reason, this might lead to problems.

Another solution that I recommend is using SQLAlchemy to convert the String type to unicode. You need to modify your model as:

```
email = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, index=True, convert_unicode=True)
```

This will basically tell SQLAlchemy to convert the value returned from the database to unicode. You can read more about it here:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String.params.convert_unicode